# is directive #region, visual studio only?

Tags: c, region

I am using the visual studio directive `#region` and I would like to know if that directive is only for **Visual Studio IDE** or it it is also recognised in a Linux IDE ?

Im afraid of portability issues.

Comment: My editor of choice has [*folding*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#region` is not part of the C standard.  I would assume that it is only recognized by Visual Studio.